# Exception in linq query for use "Type" for property name

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, casting, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a query by linq to nhibernate.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Evidence>()
       .Select(x => new Evidence(x.Id)
        {
            Type = x.Type,
            StartDate = x.StartDate,
            EndDate = x.EndDate
        })    
        .ToList();
```

It has a exception by this Message :

`NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException :
Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]
{"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
{"Specified cast is not valid."}`

But by rename `Type` property to `Type1`, My problem is resolved.

```
q = q.Select(x => new Evidence(x.Id)
    {
        Type1 = x.Type1,
        StartDate = x.StartDate,
        EndDate = x.EndDate
    });
```

Why?

Is a solution exist for use `Type` name for a property?

**UPDATE:**
Evidence class is :

```
public class Evidence
{
    public long Id;
    public EvidenceEnumType? Type;
    public DateTime? StartDate;
    public DateTime? EndDate;
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
  at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List()
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RCISP.NHibernate.Repository.EvidenceIssuanceRepositoryNh.Search(SearchEvidenceIssuanceDto dto)
   at RCISP.Domain.Services.EvidenceIssuanceService.SearchCommand(IRepositoryLocator locator, SearchEvidenceIssuanceDto dto) in D:\Users\Zeynali\Aseman\src\RCISP.Domain\Services\Issuance\EvidenceIssuanceService.cs:line 62
   at RCISP.Domain.Services.EvidenceIssuanceService.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Search>b__3(IRepositoryLocator locator) in D:\Users\Zeynali\Aseman\src\RCISP.Domain\Services\Issuance\EvidenceIssuanceService.cs:line 58
   at RCISP.NHibernate.TransManager.TransManagerNh.ExecuteCommand[TResult](Func`2 command)
```

Comment: @OskarBerggren: I added `Stack Trace`.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an NH bug to me. It would be nice if you could create a minimal test case that expose the problem and submit to NHibernate's Jira issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe You can use the `@` symbol to let the compiler know you are typing a property name:

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Evidence>()
       .Select(x => new Evidence(x.Id)
        {
            Type = x.@Type,
            StartDate = x.StartDate,
            EndDate = x.EndDate
        })    
        .ToList();
```

EDIT:
hmm I just tried making a mockup situation with:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Type;
}
```

and

```
var y = new List<MyClass>().Select(x => new MyClass() {Type = x.Type});
```

and it seems to be compiling so I see now this isn't a compile-time issue (should have been obvious by your question) but maybe a reflection issue...  so let me know if the `@` symbol actually fixes it or not...

Comment: @Richardson: I added `@` char but my problem is not resolved.

Comment: Can you try creating a constructor method for the `Evidence` class so you don't need to use the type initializer, and then use the debugger to go through and see if you can get any run-time information on why it would be failing? seems to me like it should work...  very odd.

Comment: The `@` is too allow the use of keywords as identifiers, e.g. `@event`. It does not indicate a particular type of identifier.